# Bounds on $\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

The following bounds can be found in the German wikipedia page of [Central Binomial Coefficient](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittlerer_Binomialkoeffizient)
$$\tag{$\star$}\label{star}
\frac{1}{2} \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}<\binom{2n}{n}< \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}, \quad n\ge 1.
$$
However, no proof nor reference is provided. So my question:

> Is there a simple way to derive the bounds in \eqref{star}?

References are also very welcome.

Comment: The bounds remind me very much of Stirling's formula.

Comment: I think you can use Wallis's product to prove this.  Maybe this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product.

Comment: Are you interested in this exact bound or in any estimate on $\binom{2n}{n}$? Because there are very simple bounds that are off by a factor of $n$ from each other, and a similar inequality to yours but with slightly different constants has a proof using [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality). But $\frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}$ is the true constant in the limit, and you need something as powerful as Stirling's formula to get there.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I was interested in this special bound, because it looked very simple and neat to me. Anyways, thanks for your the additional info!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By (one of the formulations of) Stirling approximation formula, you have $n!=(2\pi n)^{1/2}(n/e)^{n}e^{\theta(n)}$, with $\frac{1}{12n+1}\le \theta(n) \le \frac{1}{12n}$. Therefore, you can compute

$$(2n)!=2^{2n+1}(\pi n)^{1/2}(n/e)^{2n}e^{\theta(2n)}=2^{2n}\frac{n!^2}{(\pi n)^{1/2}} e^{\theta(2n)-2\theta(n)},$$

that is

$$ \binom{2n}{n}= \frac{2^{2n}}{(\pi n)^{1/2}} e^{\theta(2n)-2\theta(n)}.$$

Now, noting that

$\theta(2n)-2\theta(n)\le\frac{1}{24n}-\frac{2}{12n+1}<0$

and

$\theta(2n)-2\theta(n)\ge \frac{1}{24n+1}-\frac{2}{12n}\ge -\frac{1}{6}>-\log 2$,

you can conclude.